# Grouping StageName history by CreatedDate

Tags: soql, history-tracking, group-by, opportunity-history

I am struggling with this query I am trying to do. I want to count how many times we went to a specific stage grouped by weeks. There is something very strange though, I can select count(stagename) which works, and also CreatedDate, which works, but when I combine them they somehow give an error.

```
select week_in_year(createddate), Count(StageName) from OpportunityHistory where StageName = 'x'group by week_in_year(createddate)
```

I hope you guys can help me with this. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied & pasted your query to Query Editor and executed, and raised no errors.

So,

1) How did you execute a query and raised error?

2) What happens if you try it on Query Editor?

Comment: This should be posted as a comment rather than as an answer.

Comment: Oh wow, I just typed this query from memory (I was working on it yesterday) and it turns out it works. I probably had some syntax mistakes, thanks a lot though... Sorry!